# elastic search facet to aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation, facet

Need help transforming this query from using facet_filter to using aggs in ES 2.0 since facets are no longer supported in ES 2.0 and above.

```
{
  "facets": {
    "format": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "documentary_tag_id",
        "size": 10,
        "exclude": ["2"]
      },
      "facet_filter": {
        "term": {
          "documentary_tag_id": ["2"]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    "_score",
    {
      "documentary_tag_name": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I am bit confused by facet filter to filter by 2 and than in facet you have exclude 2 why it so?

Comment: its supposed to find all the documentaries with tag_id 2 and exclude 2 from the results.

Comment: Yes i see its two different fields :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregations are almost the same you should be using smth like this

```
GET _search
{
  "aggs": {
    "format_filter": {
      "filter": {
        "terms": {
          "documentary_tag_id": [
            "2"
          ]
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "format": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "documentary_tag_id",
          "exclude" : "2"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But its a bit different uproach if you [are filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.x/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html), to read value you would need to get **format_filter** then inside of it you will find aggregation. [Filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.x/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_filtering_values_with_regular_expressions) inside of aggregation is the same